# Flutter web app - Google cloud functions - throws "firebase_functions/internal" internal error - listFruit

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I've been struggling with an "internal error" in from a simple Flutter Web app that uses Google cloud functions for several days and am looking for advice on what to try next to resolve this issue.

My (test) Flutter app is very simple: a copy/paste of
https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/cloud_functions/cloud_functions/example/lib/main.dart

This app uses cloud_functions to do an httpsCallable call to a Google cloud function called "listFruit2." When the call is made however the callable() method throws "[firebase_functions/internal] internal"

My real app does the same thing.

**The Flutter App**

*A fragment of the dart code*

```
    floatingActionButton: Builder(
      builder: (context) => FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: () async {
          // See index.js in the functions folder for the example function we
          // are using for this example
          HttpsCallable callable = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable(
              'listFruit2',
              options: HttpsCallableOptions(
                  timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5)));

          await callable().then((v) {
            setState(() {
              fruit.clear();
              v.data.forEach((f) {
                fruit.add(f);
              });
            });
          }).catchError((e) {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
              content: Text('ERROR: $e'),
            ));
          });
        },
        label: const Text('Call Function'),
        icon: const Icon(Icons.cloud),
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
      ),
```

*The index.html:*

I have tried firebase-functions versions 7.14.4/7.22.1/8.2.1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Cloud Functions example app</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.22.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.22.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.22.1/firebase-functions.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize Firebase -->
<script>
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "=====",
    authDomain: "=====.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "=====.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "=====",
    storageBucket: "=====.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "=====",
    appId: "====="
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
</script>
<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*The pubspec.yaml:*

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  cloud_functions: ^1.0.0
  firebase_core: ^1.0.1

  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_driver:
    sdk: flutter
```

**The Cloud Function**

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.listFruit2 = functions.https.onCall(() => {
  return ["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Date", "Fig", "Grapes"]
});
```

*The package.json*

```
{
    "name": "functions",
    "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
    "engines": {
        "node": "12"
    },
    "main": "lib/index.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "firebase-admin": "^9.2.0",
        "firebase-functions": "^3.11.0" 
    },
    "private": true
}
```

*The deploy parameters*

```
gcloud functions deploy listFruit2 --entry-point listFruit2 --trigger-http --runtime nodejs12
```

**Flutter doctor**

```
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, 2.0.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.867], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.0.1 at C:\flutter_sdk
    • Framework revision c5a4b4029c (9 days ago), 2021-03-04 09:47:48 -0800
    • Engine revision 40441def69
    • Dart version 2.12.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\hallr\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] Connected device (2 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 88.0.4324.190
    • Edge (web)   • edge   • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 89.0.774.50

• No issues found!
```

**Other Info**

- The cloud functions work correctly from the cmd line using gcloud
- There is no indication in the cloud function logs that "listFruit2" ran from the Flutter app
- Identical "internal error" using Chrome & Edge
- No problems using cloud functions with other triggers:
  create/change/delete (i.e. problem only occurs using
  httpsCallable/onCall)
- No problems accessing/modifying Firebase storage from more complex Flutter apps

Comment: Hello, why don't you use the Firebase CLI to deploy your function?

Comment: Gcloud seems to do the job and is pretty simple. Are you asking a rhetorical question or suggesting that Firebase CLI might give more info about the problem??

Comment: "Are you asking a rhetorical question or suggesting that Firebase CLI might give more info about the problem??" I've never deployed a Callable with gcloud, that's why I asked, just to check if it will not generate a problem. It seems it should work, according to this article: https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-functions-callable. What happens if you do `gcloud functions describe listFruit2`? And what if you add `--allow-unauthenticated`when deploying?

Comment: Gcloud describe:

availableMemoryMb: 256
buildId: 149b08ba-5d6d-46b2-8e9c-6e3273e273ab
entryPoint: listFruit2
httpsTrigger:
  securityLevel: SECURE_OPTIONAL
  url: https://us-central1-====.cloudfunctions.net/listFruit2
ingressSettings: ALLOW_ALL
labels:
  deployment-tool: console-cloud
name: projects/====/locations/us-central1/functions/listFruit2
runtime: nodejs12
serviceAccountEmail: ====@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
sourceUploadUrl: https://storage.googleapis.com/gcf-upload-us-central1-...
status: ACTIVE
timeout: 60s
updateTime: '2021-03-13T16:31:37.980Z'
versionId: '7'

Comment: I do not have permission to add an unauthenticated function. That said, I think the problem is on the Flutter side. My other triggers work fine.